# Filter tableview based on an item in another tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` displaying comments which are dynamically displayed through `JSON`. On the same page, I have another UITableView as a Filter.

The filter displays a list of the types of comments. I need to filter the main tableview based on the type of comment selected from the filter tableview.

Filter `TableView1` based on item selected in `TableView2`.

**TableView1 - Main tableview

TableView2 - Filter tableview**

Following is an image of the page:

[image]

For instance, if I select "Worst Moments" in TableView2, TableView1 should display only those rows that contain the comment with "Worst Moments" as a keyword in it.

Can anyone help me with a code, how to filter items in TableView1 based on an item selected in TableView2?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me with a code

if you are asking us to code it for you then aside from the most generous souls here, most likely not.

You are almost there. This is how I would approach the problem

- What you need to do is add UISearchBar to your ViewController
- When an option is selected in TableView2 make it into a string
- Pass that string to UISearchBar
- Use that to refresh your TableView1

If you need some help you can either google UITableView & UISearchBar or you can check this Tutorial [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view).